# Jackson XML problems on Serializing

Tags: java, spring, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm having problems on serializing a list of Abstract object, jackson duplicates wrapper on tags.

Here are some results that I obtain :

```
<visibility>
    <allowed/>
    <autoSubscribed>
        <autoSubscribed>
             <regex attribute="isMemberOf" pattern="\Qxertif\E"/>
        </autoSubscribed>
    </autoSubscribed>
    <obliged>
        <obliged>
            <regex attribute="isMemberOf" pattern="\QQadddsssss\E"/>
        </obliged>
        <obliged>
            <regex attribute="isMemberOf" pattern="\Qabcdef\E"/>
        </obliged>
    </obliged>
</visibility>
```

or when i remove the @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, visible = true) from my abstract class i obtain :

```
<visibility>
    <allowed/>
    <autoSubscribed>
        <autoSubscribed attribute="isMemberOf" pattern="\Qxertif\E"/>
    </autoSubscribed>
    <obliged>
        <obliged attribute="isMemberOf" pattern="\QQadddsssss\E"/>
        <obliged attribute="isMemberOf" pattern="\Qabcdef\E"/>
    </obliged>
</visibility>
```

This is nearly good but i want the type in the tag. 
something like :

```
<visibility>
    <allowed/>
    <autoSubscribed>
        <regex attribute="isMemberOf" pattern="\Qxertif\E"/>
    </autoSubscribed>
    <obliged>
        <regex attribute="isMemberOf" pattern="\QQadddsssss\E"/>
        <regex attribute="isMemberOf" pattern="\Qabcdef\E"/>
    </obliged>
</visibility>
```

Here are my objects :

```
@Data // from lombok
public class Visibility implements Serializable {


    private List<VisibilityAbstract> allowed = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<VisibilityAbstract> autoSubscribed = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<VisibilityAbstract> obliged = new ArrayList<>();

}


@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = VisibilityGroup.class, name = "group"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = VisibilityRegex.class, name = "regex"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = VisibilityRegular.class, name = "regular")
})
public abstract class VisibilityAbstract implements Serializable {
}


@Data
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, visible = true)
@JsonTypeName(value = "group")
public class VisibilityGroup extends VisibilityAbstract implements Serializable {

    @NonNull
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String name;

}
```

All "extends" class have differents properties but are configured like VisibilityGroup.

I'm with spring boot 1.2.2 with jackson 2.4.6 and with woodstox 4.4.1.

On Json all is good, but not in XML.

Any idea on how to solve the problem ?

thanks

Comment: Try removing JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT

Comment: While not a direct solution, I would recommend trying out more recent Jackson version (2.7.4 ideally), since there have been a few fixes to XML handling since 2.4. As to solution, you will want to disable "wrapping" of `List` values using `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping=false)`. There is also a setting in `XmlMapper` to change the default for wrapping to be false.

Comment: @reos : this doesn't help, it gets the good way but childs tag name isn't good. I'm getting : <obliged>
<obliged _type="regex" attribute="isMemberOf" pattern="\Qxxxsdfsdf\E"/>
<obliged _type="regex" attribute="isMemberOf" pattern="\Qaaaabbbbb\E"/>
<obliged _type="regex" attribute="isMemberOf" pattern="\Qcccdddeeee\E"/>
</obliged>

Comment: @StaxMan: I want the wrapper because i need the parent tag <obliged> for list values, but i doesn't want a wrapper around each values inside the list

Comment: Same behaviour with spring-boot 1.2.8 and jackon 2.7.4, the problem is that all values of list are wrapped

Answer (score 1):

This may help.

```
JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
module.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper(module);
```